# Odd behavior on playing java script in a html using web browser control after download a file from the web service

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, browser

For last 2-3 weeks i am looking for a reason behind my problem. But unfortunately i could not found anything needed.

It is a Windows Phone Book reader application i am creating using c# and xaml .

For that i need to download book file from the web service and extract and save audio,image and html data from it. All data are stored in local folder.

The main functionality is that we can see highlighting of texts with the corresponding audio plays. And the high lighting functionality is done by java script function.

My problem is that the highlighting text is delaying some times and it doesn't meet with it's audio. And this is happening on the session where the book data downloaded from network or where download operation took place.

> Is there anything related to network download operation can
>   prevent/delay the execution of java script function ?
>
> Can network download operation makes any impact on Web browser control
>   ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use callback functions in JS the right way the function of eg. highlighting will start only after the loading is complete. This issue reminds me of a few things I have seen while toying with nodeJS that uses about 80% async functions and a loop. However, if you want to get things structured in JS you might want to have a look at RequireJS, but async func calls can be used anyways..

```
function highlightElement(element, function(){
  // Load document here, once this operation is done, highlighting will start
}) {
  element.addClass('active');
};
```

Comment: So what i need to try to get out of this ? Can you please clarify ? And let you know that the problem never seems to exist on the session where there is no new book data download.

Comment: Basically you hand a function into the highlight function as a parameter, so the highlight is being called after (and only after) the parameter/function has been executed. Why do you not build it entirely in JS, that might save you some headache - or are you bound to C# in any way? Still, have a look at callback functions in JS.